# How can I print unsigned char as ascii

Tags: c, unsigned-char

I'm trying to convert unsigned char to ascii text. How can I do it? 
I have tried this, but it is wrong:

```
typedef struct mtmheader
{
  unsigned char objName[20]; 
  unsigned char msgType[2];  
}mtmheader;

mtmheader h;
processMTMHeader(datap,&h, endmmsgp );
printf("Name, type: %s %c\n",(char *) &h.objName,(char *) &h.msgType);
```

**EDIT**
I read stream of unsigned bytes and want to know what how can i print is as ascii text. In printf is only pseudo code, which is wrong.

Comment: Please post an example input and what you expect as output

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("Name, type: %s %c\n", h.objName, h.msgType[0]);
```

should print the whole string `objName` and the first character from `msgType`.

For the first to work you'd have to be sure that `objName` is really null terminated.

Also `unsigned char` is not the correct type to use for strings use plain `char` without `unsigned`.

Comment: I know , that `unsigned char` is not correct. this is my problem. that why i've sent this question.